# Ping to get ip address of a server and find port number

Tags: shell, command-prompt

I want to get the port number and ip address of a server

For ip address i can

```
ping the xyz.com and to get the ip address resolved.
```

but how do i  include the port number

Comment: what do you mean 'get the port number' you need to contact the server on a particular port, the server can't tell you that as you need to know it to contact the server

Answer (score 1):

From [this Serverfault answer:](https://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port)

> You can't ping ports, as Ping is using ICMP which doesn't have the
> concept of ports. Ports belong to the transport layer protocols like
> TCP and UDP. However, you could use nmap to see whether ports are open
> or not
>
> ```
> nmap -p 80 example.com
> ```
>
> Edit: As flokra mentioned, nmap is more than
> just a ping-for-ports-thingy. It's the security auditers and hackers
> best friend and comes with tons of cool options. Check the doc for all
> possible flags.

Comment: and how do i find the port number associated with example.com ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. There is no one port "associated" with a host; many ports can be in use and usually are. (80 for www, 443 for https, others for E-Mail, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
telnet xyz.com 80
```

If it's showing output like

```
Connected to xyz.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Means your domain (xyz.com) is listening on port 80.